# cant config logstash to postgres

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

im not able to config my logstash-2.3.2 with my postgresql-9.5.4-1-windows-x64.
here's is my log-config.conf file

```
    input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ambule"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT * from table1"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

im getting 
[error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2HTqpAkzxtAVmpibDY1Zk51Vzg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the *exception* itself lies within the `jdbc_connection_string`. What if you have it as such:

```
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=username"
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ try adding the **user**

Seems like it has been missed out from the [doc](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/107). Hope it helps!